# Read consecutive memory blocks smartcard Mifare 1k

Tags: c++, visual-c++, apdu, mifare, winscard

I'm using a `Mifare 1k` card and the `acr1252` reader; I'm developing using `visual c++` and the `Winscard` library.

I've successful achieved to read the single block using the following code:

```cpp
// Read binary blocks
// Class: FF
// INS: B0
// P1: 00
// P2: the starting block number
// Le: length to read (multiple of 16)
BYTE    ReadBinary[] = { 0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x10 };

BYTE readRes[256] = { 0 };
DWORD lenRead = sizeof(readRes);

SCardTransmit(hCard, SCARD_PCI_T1, ReadBinary, sizeof(ReadBinary), NULL, readRes, &lenRead)
```

This function call returns `SCARD_S_SUCCESS` and `readRes` contains the block value + `SW1` and `SW2` with values `0x90 0x00` (success)

What i'm trying to do is reading 2 consecutive memory blocks (i.e. the block 0 and the block 1 of sector 0) using the same function only changing the apdu command with:

```
ReadBinary[] = { 0xFF, 0xB0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x20 }; 
// Last byte changed to read 2 blocks
```

But is not working: the return status still `SCARD_S_SUCCESS` but the data read contains only `SW1` and `SW2` with values `0x63 0x00` (error).

AFAIK with `Mifare 1k` cards is possible to read the first 3 blocks of a sector but all the reading tests that try to read more than a sector fail with that error.

Am i missing something?